# Are reopen requests needed?

Tags: support, reopen-request

Will [How can I stream a game through VLC to my TV?](https://superuser.com/questions/447010/gaming-via-dlna) be reopened if I change the wording enough, or should I also submit a request like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to let us know you have edited you question is to post a reopen request here on meta. 
You could also flag your question for moderator attention and request it be opened again.

The benefit of the first way is that you'll probably get some helpful advice regarding your question and that will increase the chances of it being reopened.